# Realizar una suma acumulada de items dentro de diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
d = {1: [2.6], 2: [2.4], 3: [2.5333333333333337]}
```

Busco hallar una suma acumulada en cada ítem de diccionario, he pensado en list compression, pero ese método me ha funcionado para operar dentro de cada ítem, pero no con respecto al anterior ítem como es en éste caso

Cabe aclarar que en mi caso, siempre tendré un solo ítem, ya que anterior a ello utilicé un método para promediar los valores de mis ítems.

Lo que busco es lo siguiente:

```
d = {1: [2.6], 2: [5], 3: [7.5333333333333337]}
```

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal como lo planteas, con un solo valor dentro de una lista como claves, **asumiendo que el diccionario está correctamente ordenado desde el inicio** y que usas Python >= 3.7 (dónde los diccionarios mantienen el orden de inserción), los mas simple es un ciclo `for` apoyado por una variable acumuladora:

**`Python >= 3.7`**

```
d = {1: [2.6], 2: [2.4], 3: [2.5333333333333337]}

cumsum = 0
for lista in d.values():
    cumsum = lista[0] = cumsum + lista[0]
```

Las listas por compresión que mencionas, aquí no nos sirve, si nos valdría la sintaxis de los diccionarios por compresión, siempre que quieras genera un nuevo diccionario, si no, es más ineficiente que el método in-place anterior, en Python >= 3.8 puedes hacer:

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
d = {1: [2.6], 2: [2.4], 3: [2.5333333333333337]}

cumsum = 0
cumsum_dict = {key: [(cumsum:= cumsum + value[0])] for key, value in d.items()}
```

Lo que genera una copia profunda del diccionario con las sumas acumuladas.

Si no podemos asumir el correcto orden del diccionario, pero se quiere aplicar la suma acumulada según el orden correcto de las claves, se deben ordenar previamente las claves o los items en conjunto mediante `sorted`:

```
d = {3: [2.5333333333333337], 1: [2.6], 2: [2.4]}

cumsum = 0
for key in sorted(d):
    cumsum = d[key][0] = cumsum + d[key][0]
```

---

```
cumsum = 0
for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    cumsum = value[0] = cumsum + value[0]
```

> ```
> >>> d
> {3: [7.533333333333333], 1: [2.6], 2: [5.0]}
> ```

y en el caso de querer otro diccionario:

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
d = {3: [2.5333333333333337], 1: [2.6], 2: [2.4]}

cumsum = 0
cumsum_dict = {key: [(cumsum:= cumsum + d[key][0])] for key in sorted(d)}
```

---

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
cumsum = 0
cumsum_dict = {key: [(cumsum:= cumsum + value[0])]
               for key, value in sorted(d.items())}
```

> ```
> >>> cumsum_dict
> {1: [2.6], 2: [5.0], 3: [7.533333333333333]}
> ```

Comment: Excelente tu explicación, muchas gracias @FJSevilla

Comment: ¿Cuál es la necesidad/importancia de que el diccionario esté ordenado? PD: No había caído en el acumulado.

Comment: Los dos primeros ejemplos iteran sobre las claves / items del diccionario y llevan a cabo la suma acumulada en el orden de iteración (que nada tiene que ver con un posible orden de las claves (1 < 2 < 3)), es decir, si tienes: `d = {3: [2.5333333333333337], 1: [2.6], 2: [2.4]}` el resultado es:  `{3: [2.5333333333333337], 1: [5.133333333333334], 2: [7.533333333333333]}`
. No tiene por qué estar mal, pero debes tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: En Python < 3.6 () los diccionarios no mantienen el orden de inserción, por lo que nos sabemos en que orden se itera cada vez y eso en una suma acumulada es importante.... Es decir, con las dos primeras aproximaciones en Python < 3.6 sin importar el orden de inserción original del los items en `d` una vez te puede salir `{3: [2.5333333333333337], 1: [5.133333333333334], 2: [7.533333333333333]}`, otra `{1: [2.6], 2: [5.0], 3: [7.533333333333333]}`, otra `{1: [2.6], 3: [5.133333333333334], 2: [7.533333333333333]}`, y es imposible de determinar.

Comment: En Python >= 3.7 siempre obtendrás el mismo resultado, pero debes tener en cuenta el primer comentario.